# Pass prop to child component with v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I have implemented a custom component (`InvoiceTypeAndCustomerInfo`) that utilizes a VAutocomplete element. The selected customer is passed to the component via props.

However, I am encountering an issue where the VAutocomplete does not pre-select the customer that is passed through the props when the page is initially loaded. Instead, it appears as if no customer is selected by default, even though the customer prop is correctly passed to the VAutocomplete.

Script in `InvoiceTypeAndCustomerInfo`:

```
const props = defineProps({
  invoiceType: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  customer: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
})

const customer = ref({ id: 0, fullname: '' })
const customers = ref([{ id: 1, fullname: 'Customer 1' }, { id: 2, fullname: 'Customer 2' }])
```

Template (`AppAutocomplete` is the renamed VAutocomplete):

```
<AppAutocomplete
    v-model="customer"
    :items="customers"
    item-title="fullname"
    item-value="id"
    return-object
    placeholder="Select Customer"
    class="mb-6"
    density="compact"
>
```

The parent uses `InvoiceTypeAndCustomerInfo` like this:

```
    <InvoiceTypeAndCustomerInfo 
      :customer="customer"
      :invoice-type="invoiceType" 
      @customer-changed="customerChanged"
    />
```

where customer is defined like this:

```
const customer = ref({ id: 2, fullname: 'Customer 2' })
```

Why doesn't the VAutocomplete component display the customer tfrom the props?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using `customer` twice, once as ref and once as prop. The autocomplete uses the ref, where `lastname` is empty - so there actually is a value selected, it just has no label to display.

Instead, you can use the prop directly. Just remove the ref and v-model from the AppAutocomplete, and wire it to work with the customer prop:

```
const props = defineProps(['customer'])
const emit = defineEmits(['update:customer'])
```

and in the template:

```html
<AppAutocomplete
    :modelValue="customer"
    @update:modelValue="emit('update:customer', $event)"
    ...
>
```

Now you can do `<InvoiceTypeAndCustomerInfo v-model:customer="yourCustomer"/>`

---

Alternatively, you can rename the ref and use a watcher to copy the prop value to the internal ref. This depends on how you want to use the component, particularly how you emit the update event, which is not specified in the question. But in any way, you will use watcher like:

```
const selectedCustomer = ref()
watch(
  () => props.customer,
  () => selectedCustomer.value = props.customer,
  {immediate: true}
)
```

and

```html
<AppAutocomplete
  v-model="selectedCustomer"
  ...
```

Now any update to customer on `InvoiceTypeAndCustomerInfo` will update the selected value.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply.The fullname here is the default which must be overridden by the object that should come from the parent. I tested the data that passed by the parent and I can confirm I can read the data in the child compnent. The problem is related to the VAutocomplete.

Comment: @A.Student Please add the code to your question then, particularly the part where you pass the `modelValue` on `AppAutocomplete` to `v-autocomplete`

Comment: Thank you @Morits Ringler, good observation. In fact, the AppAutocomplete is the VAutocomplete itself (there is NO AppAutocompllete). And I don't use the modelValue, I use the customer ref on both the parent and the child component. Also, I use the same name as a prop. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Alright, let me guess again... Check the updated answer. Is this what you are asking for?